# JavaScript math functions doesn't make sense

Tags: javascript, animation

I am new to JavaScript animations and trigonometry. I am learning it these days for future use. I seen people using trigonometric functions sin, cos , tan and math.pi everywhere in graphics programs. I found this code snippet from website and i don't understand why he's using them. Can you help me to understand them .. thanks.

```
var stage = document.querySelector('.stage'),
  `enter code here`  message = 'Smashing Magazine '.toUpperCase(),
    plots = message.length;
    increase = Math.PI * 2 / plots,
    angle = -Math.PI,
    turnangle = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    plotcache = [];

for( var i = 0; i < plots; i++ ) {
  var p = new Plot( stage );
  p.content( message.substr(i,1) );
  p.setDimensions( 40, 40 );
  plotcache.push( p );
}
function rotate(){
  for( var i = 0; i < plots; i++ ) {
    x = 100 * Math.cos( angle ) + 200;
    y = 100 * Math.sin( angle ) + 200;
    // rotation and rotating the text 90 degrees
    turnangle = Math.atan2( y - 200, x - 200 ) * 180 / Math.PI + 90 + 'deg';
    plotcache[ i ].rotate( turnangle );
    plotcache[ i ].position( x, y );
    angle += increase;
  }
  angle += 0.06;
}

setInterval( rotate, 1000/40 );
```

Comment: Link to the website?

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/quick-look-math-animations-javascript/

Comment: Plotting curves using angles.

Comment: Can u explain it to me. I don't understand how it works.

Comment: You can look at a curve as the intersection of one or more points on a flat or three dimensional graph. At any point, given a fixed section of the graph, you can plot the inclination or declination of a moving point by calculating or measuring the distance between x,y,z intersections. See http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/cartesian-coordinates.html , http://mathinsight.org/spherical_coordinates , http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat169/fall09/lecture17.pdf, http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_summer_06/handouts/coordinates.pdf